# Hyperlink action in power bi table

Tags: powerbi

I have create a power bi report which contains a table with several columns.

This column contains a list of customers.

What i want to do is to allow user to click on one customer (on one row).
I want to open another table to see the customer's invoices list.

Is it possible to do that with power bi.

I have read a lot of documentation and it does not seem to be possible.

I am asking you because i do not want to miss something

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes possible. You can check **Drill Through** or **Tool-tip** options in Power BI. In case of Drill Through, you will need to design a new page with the Invoice details considering a customer and enable the Drill Down option of this page. Finally when you will right click on a specific customer, you will get an option to navigate to that Invoice page. After navigate to that page, you will get the Invoice for that customer you right clicked.

In case of Tool-tip, here you also need to design a separate page with Tool-tip enabled. In this case, if you configure everything correct, you will able to see the invoice as a pop up window rather than opening a new page.

Now you can select the appropriate option for you and there are lot of tutorial available explaining how Drill Through and Tool-tip works in Power BI

**=====Work Around======**

Here is an alternative option to **tool-tip** and drill **through**-

For example you have a page with **Region** list. Just add a **Blank Button** below the list and change the type as below-

[image]

Now create your Invoice page and add **Region** to the drill through property as shown below-

[image]

Now go back to main page and map the invoice page to the button as shown below-

[image]

Now, the invoice button will only enable when a Region is selected in the list and when you click on the button, this will open the Invoice page for the selected Region.

**Sample screen shoot-**

**1.** No Region selected, button is disabled-

[image]

**2.** One region selected and the button is enabled now-

[image]

**3.** Button enabled as Asia is selected. When click on the button it opened the Invoice page with Asia data-

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot: I know drill through or tool-tip but there is no way to clic on row ? I need to right clic and select drill through in popup menu. What i want is an hyperlink inside the table. No way to do that ?

Comment: For popup, you just need to hover on the mouse on specific customer.

Comment: What you mean by popup is tool tip ? I want to show another page (full report screen with back Burton)

Comment: That case drill through is the option.

Comment: Yes but i cannot simply click on the row: I need to right click and follow "drill through" in context menu. This is not user friendly...

Comment: Yes, that's a bad side considering end user.

Comment: Okay so you confirm me it is absolutely impossible to add an hyperlink in a table row ?

Comment: Adding hyperlink in table cell is possible. But I am not sure that can be linked to another page or not. Normally that link refer to external web sites.

Comment: Hi @Bob5421, I have added an alternative option to avoid Right click. Please check.